# How to fetch products with the price in a page on woocommerce using a form or live search with php

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, customization, categories

Hi I have built a multivendor marketplace and would like to another feature that allows shoppers to create shopping lists which they can always reuse or edit. And i cant find a plugin that can enable that. So i was thinking of any php script that can help using a live search or form to fetch products and then when customers selects the products the item and its price is populated in a table format below and that can be synced with the cart